# How to add a "Total" to categorical variables barchart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a data set that has two categorical variables. I am going to summarize the data by having one of these categorical variables on the x-axis, and the counts of the other variable as bars on the y-axis.

Is there an easy way to collapse all of the x-axis variables to a "Total" that can be appended to the figure? Something like this:

[image]

I should mention that this will be a stacked bar chart and have three "totals", one for each categorical response.

Comment: Not once you've started the ggplot call. You're better off summarizing the data beforehand and then creating the plot.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a `table` output, then we can use `addmargins`

```
barplot(t(addmargins(table(v1, v2), 1)))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
v1 <- sample(c("Man", "Woman", "Legal Person", "Physical Person"), 
        100, replace = TRUE)
v2 <-  sample(1:4, 100, replace = TRUE)
```